# Cloned site in subdirectory keeps redirecting to root

Tags: redirect, clone-site

I used the Duplicator plugin to make a copy of my main https://l4jp.com site in a subdirectory "old" so I could do comparisons between versions of a theme and fix CSS problems. I can access the main landing URL https://l4jp.com/old, but any other frontend URL associated with that site (whether from navigation on the site or input directly in the browser) gets a 301 redirect to the main site (i.e. the "old/" in the middle of the URL is removed). I've checked wp-config.php and .htaccess for oddities, but I didn't spot anything obvious.

There are two pieces of evidence that it's Wordpress doing the redirect: (1) `https://l4jp.com/old/wp-admin/` does not redirect - the problem is only the frontend; (2) running `curl -v https://l4jp.com/old/about-en/` reports the following:

```
> GET /old/about-en/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: l4jp.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2023 06:17:05 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< X-Redirect-By: WordPress
< Location: https://l4jp.com/about-en/
```

I don't know what some of that means (including what expires in 1984!), but `X-Redirect-By: WordPress` seems pretty clear. Suggestions on what to look for?